# Create field for auto generated integer in symfony doctrine in YML

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am having the primary key as uuid type and having some fields in yml with mapped domain in entity

Need to add another unique id in the table with auto generated integer
I have tried an generator strategy auto but it didn't work for me below is my yml file

```
Sample\Component\Group\Domain\Group:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Sample\Component\Group\Infrastructure\Persistence\Doctrine\Repository\DoctrineGroupRepository
  table: group
  oneToMany:
    merchants:
      targetEntity: Sample\Component\Merchant\Domain\Merchant
      mappedBy: group
      fetch: LAZY
      cascade: ["all"]
      orphanRemoval: true
  id:
    groupId:
      type: group_id
      column: group_id

  fields:
    gId:
      type: integer
      column: g_id
      unique: true
      nullable: TRUE
      generator:
        strategy: Identity
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
```

In this id groupId is the uuid primary key

Need to create gId auto increment field

Also tried generator strategy auto and Identity

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
id:
  id:
    type: integer
    generator:
      strategy: AUTO
```

Auto means its unique

Comment: If I tried this "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\NotNullConstraintViolationException" error occurs

Comment: What is status of you nullable: is it TRUE or FALSE if its FALSE make sure your table isn't populated before .
If table is already populated then make it TRUE

Comment: If I use the nullable true the integer was not autogenerated empty value in that field

Comment: Your table is populated before ?

Comment: Yes I have created mytable before

Comment: You should run this Query 
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
and then define it to your yml file.
Actually issue is you already have populated table so when you create new unique id it violates not null constrain.

Comment: Actually I am having another primary key groupId

Comment: CompositePrimary Key

Comment: Is this a solution for that

Comment: Yes The one i know but there is always other ways you can continue exploring

Comment: Okay I will try to use any one of these